# Insert rows based on cell value using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to insert rows with random data based on a cell value.
Example: If A1 cell is having=4, it should insert 4 rows in Name, Age(random value) columns

I want to do it using formulas not by macro

Comment: Random data of names as well?

Comment: names i got that, using =CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90)), i just want to populate the rows based on cell value.

Comment: Formulas do not insert rows. If a range of cells has been prepopulated with a formula, that formula can return a zero-length string (e.g. `""`) which changes to `CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90))` depending on the value in another cell but formulas do not insert rows.

Comment: yeah you are right, I'm new to Excel. I'm able to do it based on condition like (a1<>a2, generate random data). Now i want to do based on cell value, any inputs I will be thankful to you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say D1 is the header name and E1 is the header age

Enter on D2 For name:

```
=IF($A$1>=ROW(D1),CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90)),"")
```

and on E2 for age:

```
=IF($A$1>=ROW(D1),RANDBETWEEN(1,120),"")
```

You can drag both formulas to the max amount of numbers you desire.